# Suggestion for Probability theory

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am following the book *Probability Book by Albert Shiryaev*. This includes all the topics that I am going to cover in my course work fo this year. I find it a bit more sophisticated and advanced for me. Can anyone please suggest an alternative reference book which I can follow? Or a book to follow first after which I can dive into Shiryaev (as it is recommended to study).

Comment: Billinglsely's Probability and Measure is a  good book. For a good measure theoretic background the book by K L Chung is good.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you for your suggestions. I will go through them.